# Java Spring testing without Spring Boot - error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, testing

I am learning Java Spring Framework. I am at a very beginning. As I have read it is better to start with Spring, not Spring Boot, when one learns Spring. I have a very simple testing that is to display a string only. I found the application in a tutorial, but it was tested with Spring Boot, so I tried to convert it to Spring. But then it threw the error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`

Please help me to fix it in Spring without Spring Boot. Below a log and files are listed.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/bin/java -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:/opt/idea-IU/lib/idea_rt.jar=33619:/opt/idea-IU/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/idea-IU/lib/idea_rt.jar:/opt/idea-IU/plugins/junit/lib/junit5-rt.jar:/opt/idea-IU/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/u/Dropbox/IdeaProjects/injection/target/test-classes:/home/u/Dropbox/IdeaProjects/injection/target/classes:/home/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/u/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/u/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-context-support-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-test/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-test-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/u/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.12/lombok-1.18.12.jar:/home/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-test/2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-test-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/u/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/u/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.13/junit-4.13.jar:/home/u/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 guru.springframework.dibestpractices.ControllerTest
Jul 25, 2020 2:02:21 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper getDefaultTestExecutionListenerClassNames
INFO: Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener]
Jul 25, 2020 2:02:21 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper getTestExecutionListeners
INFO: Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@4dfa3a9d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@6eebc39e, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@464bee09, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@f6c48ac, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@13deb50e, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@239963d8]
Jul 25, 2020 2:02:21 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bpFinalConstructorController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'guru.springframework.dibestpractices.BpService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Jul 25, 2020 2:02:21 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@464bee09] to prepare test instance [guru.springframework.dibestpractices.ControllerTest@54c562f7]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bpFinalConstructorController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'guru.springframework.dibestpractices.BpService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:275)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'guru.springframework.dibestpractices.BpService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:778)
    ... 43 more


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bpFinalConstructorController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'guru.springframework.dibestpractices.BpService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:275)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'guru.springframework.dibestpractices.BpService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:778)
    ... 43 more


Process finished with exit code 255
```

---

---

*./pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>injection</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aopalliance/aopalliance -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

*./src/test/java/guru/springframework/dibestpractices/ControllerTest.java*

```
package guru.springframework.dibestpractices;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { BpFinalConstructorController.class })
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    BpFinalConstructorController bpFinalConstructorController;

    @Test
    public void testFieldController() {
        System.out.println("A Best Practice Controller says: " + bpFinalConstructorController.saySomething());
    }
}
```

---

*./src/main/java/guru/springframework/dibestpractices/BpFinalConstructorController.java*

```
package guru.springframework.dibestpractices;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
@Component
public class BpFinalConstructorController {
    private final BpService bpService;

    public String saySomething() {
        return bpService.getHello();
    }
}
```

---

*./src/main/java/guru/springframework/dibestpractices/BpServiceImpl.java*

```
package guru.springframework.dibestpractices;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class BpServiceImpl implements BpService {
    @Override
    public String getHello() {
        return "The Best Hello!";
    }
}
```

---

*./src/main/java/guru/springframework/dibestpractices/BpService.java*

```
package guru.springframework.dibestpractices;

public interface BpService {
    String getHello();
}
```

### Update

I did changes mentioned by Siddharth Agrawal in his answer and it worked. I also did some small deletions in the code, so 3 files got chnaged:

*./src/test/java/guru/springframework/dibestpractices/ControllerTest.java*

```
package guru.springframework.dibestpractices;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { BpFinalConstructorController.class, BpServiceImpl.class })

public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    BpFinalConstructorController bpFinalConstructorController;

    @Bean
    public BpService bpService() {
        return new BpServiceImpl();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFieldController() {
        System.out.println("A Best Practice Controller says: " + bpFinalConstructorController.saySomething());
    }
}
```

---

*./src/main/java/guru/springframework/dibestpractices/BpFinalConstructorController.java*

```
package guru.springframework.dibestpractices;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BpFinalConstructorController {
    private final BpService bpService;

    public String saySomething() {
        return bpService.getHello();
    }
}
```

---

*./src/main/java/guru/springframework/dibestpractices/BpServiceImpl.java*

```
package guru.springframework.dibestpractices;

public class BpServiceImpl implements BpService {
    @Override
    public String getHello() {
        return "The Best Hello!";
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using BpServiceImpl  as a dependency in  BpFinalConstructorController  so provide a bean for this as well. or you can use @InjectMock on controller and Mock  BpServiceImpl

Comment: Not what you asked but Spring Boot is just Spring but more opinionated abstracting away lot of the stuff you have to do manually if you use plain Spring. So I would say if you are beginner, learn Spring Boot first and then if you feel that it is too opinionated to fit your needs learn how to change stuff that Boot autoconfigures. More info here: https://codeboje.de/learn-spring-boot-without-spring-knowhow/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of unsatisfied dependency in your controller's constructor.
In your controller:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
@Component
public class BpFinalConstructorController {
    private final BpService bpService;

    public String saySomething() {
        return bpService.getHello();
    }
}
```

The `@RequiredArgsConstructor` annotation dynamically generates this constructor:

```
public BpFinalConstructorController(BpService bpService) {
    this.bpService = bpService;
}
```

So in your test class, you need to provide a bean for this `BpService` class.
Include `BpServiceImpl.class` in your test's `@ContextConfiguration` and it should work.